# Remove id from parent window from an iframe

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

For various reasons I am stuck trying to remove a parent div from a function coming from an iframe.  The div that needs to be removed from the dom (not hidden) has a unique id assigned to it.

So say I have this div in parent :

```
<body>
    <div id="foo_123" class="bar">STUFF</div>
```

In the iframe generated from that page I have this to grab that unique id

```
var curWin = window.top.document.getElementsByClassName('bar')[0].id;
```

so in this example `curWin = foo_123`

Now in the same function that gets that variable I need to be able to remove that div completely from the parent page.  I do have prototype to work with and I tried doing

```
$(curWin).remove();
```

But that did not work it just gives error that `$(curWin) is null`.  But if I echo curWin it does provide me with that correct id.

Any ideas on how I can do this.  I tried using `removeChild` too but again I am not sure how to do it when it is the child of the `<body>` in the parent document.

Please refrain from telling me how awesome jQuery is.  I know this would be easy beans but I do not have that luxury with this project.

Comment: Forgive me because I've been pampered with jQuery but if `curWin` contains the string of the elements id, wouldn't you want to use `document.getElementById(curWin).remove()`?

Comment: @Neurotrace, `.remove` is jQuery sugar, normal element's dont have that. Normally to remove an element without any framework you'd do `elemRef.parentNode.removeChild( elemRef );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have prototype in the top window do:

`top.$(curWin).remove();`

It will look for `"foo_123"` in the top window (where it exists) instead of the iframe (where it doesn't exist)

Comment: Ahhhh yes! An hour of pounding my head on the desk = no result.  5 minutes on SO = success!  Thanks.  I will accept as soon as I can.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`parent.document`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.parent), not [`window.top`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.top). Also, grab the whole element, not the ID:

```
var curWin = parent.document.getElementsByClassName('bar')[0];
curWin.parentNode.removeChild(curWin);
```

**Additional Information:**

[MDN iframe docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/iframe) quote:

> From the inside of a frame, a script can get a reference to the parent
>   window via **window.parent**.

See also, [`.removeChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.removeChild)

Answer (score 0):

Pass the element reference for the Prototype, will be faster then re-search and probably will work:

```
var curWin = window.top.document.getElementsByClassName('bar')[0]
```

Then you can:

```
$(curWin).remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way I have found to get to elements from the parent thru an iFrame is like this (note your iframe would have an id and as shown I used #iframID )

```
x=document.getElementById("iframID");
y=(x.contentWindow || x.contentDocument);
$(y.document).find("#foo_123").remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var curWin = parent.top.document.getElementById('yourDivId');
$(curWin).remove();
```